# How to make automatic migrations on Phoenix / Ecto?

Tags: elixir

I come from a python / django background where a simple `python manage.py makemigrations` was generating my migration.

Now the question is, with Ecto, I do not find commands like that. It seems i have to use `mix ecto.gen.migration` and then fill the migration manually. It will not detect changes in my model automatically, I have to fill it manually.

Do you have any ideas how to generate the migration almost automatically (for instance if I am adding a field in an existing model).

Comment: This functionality somewhat goes against how Ecto works. Ecto schemas are not necessarily mapped one-to-one with a database table. It is possible, even encouraged depending on the complexity of your application, to have multiple schemas backed by a single table. How would you decide which fields to add / remove from your migration if a single schema does not hold all fields of your database?

Answer (score 3):

As of [the latest relevant commit](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/d37ad7b6c92fd4b24cf1d8774c7cc56b2787be95/lib/mix/tasks/ecto.gen.migration.ex), June 2018, this functionality is not there.

As an idea, why not try and parse the `schema` clause in the model, compare it to the underlying database and generate the statements based on the difference? Should be doable but probably not quite easy.